# How to apply (on conflict do nothing) using django get_or_create()

Tags: django, django-views

Lets say the first_name and last_name are as below in Models.py:

```
unique_together = ('first_name', 'last_name',)
```

and in view.py

```
obj, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(
    first_name='John',
    last_name='Lennon',
    defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)},
)
```

But sometimes I get an error caused by duplication: 
Normally in Postgres I use  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING while inserting. What is the best way in Django to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Why can't you catch the error and ignore it?

Comment: Do you mean the bulk methode or just try and except?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to catch the `IntegrityError` which should be raised if duplicate key(s) are to be inserted in the database:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError


try:
    obj, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(
        first_name='John',
        last_name='Lennon',
        defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)},
    )
except IntegrityError:
    pass
```

You can read more about the Django database exceptions here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.db.IntegrityError

Comment: but you cannot choose which constraint to ignore?